# python Recursion function dought

Tags: python

I got an answer to my task in python.But I had a dought that 
what is the difference between the empty list inside the function and outside the function?

why i am asking this because, my expected output came while i am declaring the empty list outside the function but not inside the function. Also I dont know how the output value in my list (5230) came in my output ? first three output value i know what happening in my program but last value in my list i dont know how that value came ?

my task question is 
A 10-SUBSTRING OF A NUMBER IS A SUBSTRING OF ITS DIGITS THAT SUM UPTO 10 ALSO BE IN A ORDERED SEQUENCE OF THE GIVEN STRING ?

```
THE STRING IS '3523014'
EXPECTED OUTPUT : ['352','523','23014','5230']
```

MY CODE USING RECURSION.

```
    l=[]
    def ten_str(s):
        x,z,p=0,1,1
        for i in s:
            x+=eval(i)
            if x==10:
                l.append(s[:z])
                ten_str(s[p:])
                p+=1
            z+=1
        return l
    print(ten_str('3523014'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the empty list inside the function, then each time the function is recursively called it will create a new empty list.  Strings meeting the condition will be lost when that recursive call ends, rather than being added to the global list.  I find http://pythontutor.com/ helps a lot with recursion exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, a 10-substring is a set of values in the original order of the list when added sum up to 10.

5+2+3+0 = 10. Your list 3**5230**14 contains 5230

Comment: Thats ok, i understand the first three string in my list but the recursion got ended when the strings gets complete that is upto that three strings in the list and program also ended. Then how that last string of 5230 in my list came ?